# How to convert String format dates to Date format dates?

Tags: android, date

I have a string with dates it looks like: "20120316 20120317 20120318" ... I store this dates in this format, but I would like to make a Date array from these numbers with the format 03/16 03/17 03/18 ...

So far:

```
 String[] DailyDatasOnce2 = DatesOnce.split(" ");   

         DailyDatasOnce = new String[DailyDatasOnce2.length];
         for (int i=0;i< (DailyDatasOnce2.length) ;i++){
             DailyDatasOnce[i]=DailyDatasOnce2[i];
         }

         datumok = new Date[DailyDatasOnce.length];

         for (int i=0;i< (DailyDatasOnce.length) ;i++){

            SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"); 

            java.util.Date dateObj = null;
            java.util.Date dateObj2 = null;
            try {
                dateObj = curFormater.parse(DailyDatasOnce[i]);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd"); 

            String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj); 

            try {
                dateObj2 = curFormater.parse(newDateStr);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            datumok[i] = dateObj2;

         }
```

So first I make a string array with the string dates (DailyDatasOnce), maybe that first `for` loop is useless but i can skip it. Now I make a Date array and I want to put the dates into it. I format the dates to format I want, then I try to convert them to Date format. Until  the `String newDateStr` it is working, I manage to change the type of the date. 
But I get syntax error for the last row: Type mismatch: Cannot convert from java.util.date to java.sql.data.
I suspect the problem but if it is not possible, how can i do this?

Comment: replace `import java.sql.Date;` with `import java.util.Date;`. That's causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I recommend:

```
DateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
fromFormat.setLenient(false);
DateFormat toFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
toFormat.setLenient(false);
String fromDate = "20120316";
Date d = fromFormat.parse(fromDate); // this is a java.util.Date
System.out.println(String.format("date is %s", toFormat.format(d));
```

You don't need two Dates, just one; you need *to* and *from* formats.

It must be `java.util.Date`.

If you have a collection, just do this:

```
String [] dateStrings = datesOnce.split(" ");
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
for (String dateString : dateStrings) {
    dates.add(fromFormat.parse(dateString));
}
```

You can format all those Dates any way you wish.

If it must be a Date array, do it this way:

```
String [] dateStrings = datesOnce.split(" ");
Date [] dates = new Date[dateStrings.length];
int i = 0; 
for (String dateString : dateStrings) {
    dates[i++] = fromFormat.parse(dateString);
}
```

Here's a complete demo:

```
package homework;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * DateFormatDemo
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796520/how-to-convert-string-format-dates-to-date-format-dates/9796619#comment12475521_9796619
 * @since 3/20/12 8:55 PM
 */
public class DateFormatDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "20120316 20120317 20120318";
        DateFormat fromFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        fromFormat.setLenient(false);
        DateFormat toFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
        toFormat.setLenient(false);
        String [] dateStrings = input.split("\\s+");
        Date [] dates = new Date[dateStrings.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (String dateString : dateStrings) {
            try {
                dates[i++] = fromFormat.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        for (Date d : dates) {
            System.out.println(toFormat.format(d));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I put this into a date array? Sorry for the obvious question I am a beignner

Comment: I think I showed you, did I not?  Let me spell it out for you.

Comment: I dont know why but I get datas like 13400000000 and 1321000000000

Comment: Those might be the long values that represent the milliseconds since midnight of 1-Jan-1970 for those dates.  Did you cut & paste the code I posted?  Try this stuff, separate from yours.

Comment: I didnt cut it. The first 4 rows then the last 6 rows. After that I put it into achartengine, and since it handles date format, I dont know what is the problem.

Comment: how can I log it anyway? I tried  DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext()); But this changes the date format

Comment: Yes it definetly works. But what on earth is happening with the achartengine.. I give the dates parameter as the date arg, and get this silly numbers.. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

or that

```
public static String[] getDates(String longDateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
    String[] inputDates = longDateString.split(" ");
    String[] outputDates = new String[inputDates.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputDates.length; i++) {
        try {
            Date date = inputFormater.parse(inputDates[i]);
            outputDates[i] = outputFormater.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            outputDates[i] = "cannot parse"; 
        }
    }
    return outputDates;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its working as well, but the same problem when I put the values into achartengine.. I will probably ask it in antoher question.

Comment: are you sure that achartengine can handle an array of date strings in that format? Maybe it expects a different input

Comment: http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html Down as you see, the user can define any date type it will handle it. I tried a very usual format and I get the same numbers

Comment: http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/chart/TimeChart.html is probably what you use and that expects dates as `double` not in text format / http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/model/TimeSeries.html wants dates as `Date`

Comment: So I had a string, converted to date, and now it cant handle it. If I define 20120306 as double and convert it to date (not sure how), you think its going to work?

Comment: That is wierd. It wants java.util.Date x .. and this is the format I convert the string to..

Comment: maybe then you are missing some of the setup parameters, like that one maybe `timechart.setDateFormat("MM/dd");`

Comment: yes, maybe I miss it. But I am new to this API and cant find how to put this paramerer for the chart, since I can use this parameter only if I define the chart as a timechart. So I pose it as a question. Anyway, thank you again, I probably miss it, but i am not aware of the syntax of achartengine.

Comment: No, you should not be defining anything as a double.  Date uses a long.  Make sure you have one.